# How to fix no provider for localStorage and circular dependency

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I have an angular frontend project generated with nrwl nx. After implementing an interceptor I am getting the following two errors after trying to make a request:

The first call causes this one:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> [object Object] -> LocalStorageService -> LocalStorageService -> LocalStorageService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for LocalStorageService!
```

THe second call of the same request right after the first one causes this one:

```
ERROR Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS. Find more at
```

The funny thing is I have provided my interceptor in my app.module, I thought this was enough and the second error confuses me greatly as I did not import or use the interceptor directly. I hope someone here can help me out:

App-module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NbLayoutModule,
    LoginComponentModule,
    DashboardModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NbThemeModule.forRoot({name: 'default'}),
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbEvaIconsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    }

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

interceptor:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorageService, private sessionStorage: SessionStorageService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!request.url || (request.url.startsWith('http') && !(environment.rootUrl && request.url.startsWith(environment.rootUrl)))) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    const token =
      this.localStorage.retrieve('token') ||
      this.sessionStorage.retrieve('token');
    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
      });

    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Authentication service:

```
    export class AuthenticationService{
      isAuthenticated = false;
    
      constructor(
        private handler: HttpBackend,
        private http: HttpClient,
        private router: Router,
      ) {
      }
    
      authenticateUser(login: LoginModel){
        this.http = new HttpClient(this.handler)
        return this.http.post(environment.rootUrl + 'api/authenticate', {
          username: login.username,
          password: login.password,
        }).subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
           localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data))
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
    
          }, error: (error) => {
            this.isAuthenticated = false
          }
        })
      }

  isUserLoggedIn(){
    return !!localStorage.getItem('token')
  }
```

and material service which makes a request:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MaterialService {

  constructor(private httpRequest: HttpClient) { }

  getMaterials() {
    return this.httpRequest.get("/api/product/api/materials")
  }


}
```

I have other modules but as far as I understand if I provided it in the app-module it should be enough, at least I thought so. I hope you guys can help me out

EDIT added the codes where authentication service is used:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if (this.auth.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['authenticate'])
        resolve(false)
      }
    })

  }
}
```

login.component:

```
export class LoginComponent {

  status = 'basic'

  userNameErrorText= 'Username is required'
  passwordErrorText= 'Password is required'

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }
  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    userNameInput: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    passwordInput: new FormControl('',  [Validators.required])
  })

  public hasError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) =>{
    return this.loginForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  }

  login(){
    if(this.loginForm.valid){
      this.authService.authenticateUser({
        username: this.loginForm.controls['userNameInput'].value,
        password: this.loginForm.controls['passwordInput'].value
      })
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Where have you used the auth service ? I don't see any usage in Interceptor

Comment: Can you also include the `LocalStorageService` implementation?

Comment: Hi, the auth service is called from a simple component. I could later post it I’m not at home right now. I don’t have a LocalStorageService implementation just the instantiating from auth intercepter

Comment: There is no instantiation going on in the `AuthInterceptor`, you expect the DI container to provide that for you; that's why I asked to see it.

Comment: How would I have to do it? Like I said I don’t have any service for localstorage. Something like this.local storage=new lovalstorage?

Comment: LocalstorageService is a service from ngx that is why I thought it would work like this....

Comment: added the components which call authentication service

Comment: it is fixed I replaced localStorageService with localstorage and it worked